# Conceptual - How to build a 2D word-frequency matrix in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, text, dictionary, categorization

I'm trying to practice a logistic regression technique for categorizing text, and I want to build a dataset in the form of a p x n matrix, p rows for plays and n columns for unique words. I already have a text to work from, I just need to count the words in it.

It's important to keep track of which word occurs in which play, so for a given play I've been able to create a Python dictionary that tallies unique words. What I DON'T know how to do is to combine these dicts, so that, e.g.

```
romeo = {[alas,2],[julliet,35]}
caesar = {[et,1],[tu,3],[cassius,12]}
```

can be merged to produce a matrix

```
      alas  julliet  et  tu cassius
romeo  2        35    0   0  0 
caesar 0        0     1   3  12
```

For clarity I created an example where each play is composed only of unique words - naturally in reality this is not at all true.

How might someone go about building this matrix from these dictionaries? Would it be easier to start from somewhere else?

Comment: What format do you want your resulting matrix in? Python itself doesn't have a native 2d-array data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, tested:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

romeo = {'alas':2, 'juliet':35, 'hello':1}
caesar = {'et':1, 'tu':3, 'cassius':12, 'hello':1}

dicts = defaultdict(dict)
dicts['romeo'] = romeo
dicts['caesar'] = caesar

columns = list(set(list(chain(romeo.keys(), caesar.keys()))))

matrix = defaultdict(dict)

for coll in ('romeo', 'caesar'):
    matrix[coll] = {}
    for key in columns:
        if dicts[coll].has_key(key):
            matrix[coll][key] = dicts[coll][key]
        else:
            matrix[coll][key] = 0

print columns

for coll in matrix.keys():
    for key in columns:
        print matrix[coll][key], 
    print '\n'
```

Explanation: combine all the keys from both dictionaries together, then run loops and populate a brand new dict of dicts :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use nested dictionaries, or 2-dimensional dictionaries. For nested, first, you need to change the format of your dicitonary to a proper form:

```
romeo = {[alas,2],[julliet,35]}
caesar = {[et,1],[tu,3],[cassius,12]}
```

should be:

```
romeo = {'alas':2,'julliet': 35}
caesar = {'et':1,'tu':3,'cassius':12}
```

From there, you can loop through all of the "values" in the dictionary and nest the dictionaries so instead of a matrix as you have it, you can have something like:

```
#declare first:
Ds = {{}}
```

Then use loop to populate:

```
Ds = {
      'romeo' : {'et': 0, 'alas':2,'julliet': 35, tu':0,'cassius':0}, 
      'caesar' :  {'et':1, 'alas':0, 'julliet': 0, 'tu':3,'cassius':12}
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I ended up doing was implementing a defaultdict because I liked how it would create dictionaries or dictionary entries (depending on location) when a reference didn't previously exist.

I built a full defaultdict with what I wanted, and then ploddingly output to CSV.

I used the full text dump from opensourceshakespeare.com, here's what I wrote:

```
    playNames = {}

    for line in listOfLines:
            try:
                    playNames[line.rsplit('~')[0]] += 1
                    if line.rsplit('~')[0] == '':
                        print line
            except:
                    playNames[line.rsplit('~')[0]] = 1

    #print playNames.keys()

    #
    # Now let's build a dictionary for each play
    #

    for line in listOfLines:

            try:
                    playNames[line.rsplit('~')[0]] += line.rsplit('~,~')[2]
                    playNames[line.rsplit('~')[0]] += " "
            except:
                    playNames[line.rsplit('~')[0]] = line.rsplit('~,~')[2]
                    playNames[line.rsplit('~')[0]]+= " "

    #
    # for each play, tokenize text into list of words
    #

    for key in playNames.iterkeys():
            playNames[key] = playNames[key].split(' ')

    plays = collections.defaultdict(dict)

    for key in playNames.iterkeys():
            for val in playNames[key]:
                    try:
                            plays[key][val] += 1
                    except:
                            plays[key][val] = 1

    #
    # build a set of words
    #

    words = set()

    for eachplay in plays.itervalues():
            words.update(eachplay.keys())

    outfile = open("wordlist.csv",'w')

    i=0
    outfile.write(",")
    for word in words:

            outfile.write(word)
            outfile.write(",")
            i+=1
    print "words ",i

    outfile.write("\n")
    for eachplay in plays.iterkeys():
            i = 0
            outfile.write(eachplay)

            outfile.write(",")
            for word in words:
                    try:
                            outfile.write(str(plays[eachplay].get(word,"0")))
                            #print word,plays[eachplay][word]
                    except:
                         outfile.write("")
                    i+=1
                    outfile.write(",")
            outfile.write("\n")
            print eachplay," ",i
    outfile.close()
```